# ostream::flush context

Tags: linux, multithreading, real-time

I am using both `ostream::write` and `ostream::flush` operation in a multithread application in the following sequence:

```
// <<--  start time measurement
{
ostream::write();
ostream::flush();
}
//<<--  end time measurement
```

The issue it that on measuring the time for the above sequence, I get a very short time (~10msec), yet the time between thread entrance becomes very large (~400msec), only because of adding the `ostream::flush` and `ostream:::write` commands.
Only oncee in a while I get that the time difference becomes larger, yet I am not sure if it is because of some context switch.

I test it in Linux machine, dual core cpu.

This make me confused, **I have assumed that both of these functions are blocking, or is it that the writing is actually done only after `fflush` ?**

**EDIT**:

only one thread does the writing to file.

Comment: Each operation locks a mutex. Your poor performance is pretty much certainly due to lock contention. You could get better performance if you associated each thread with its own io buffer and used fwrite_unlocked() and fflush_unlocked() if that's possible in the context of your program.

Comment: Writing is done when the file buffer fills up (if the file is block-buffered, when a newline is encountered (if it's line-buffered) or when you call fflush (always; as long as there's something in the buffer).

Comment: In anycase, I don't think it's very clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: I've edited the question